# How can I open a file with Notepad without permanently associating its extension with Notepad?

Tags: windows, windows-8, file-extension

I’m a developer; I basically work in a Windows 8 environment with several virtual machines running Linux, Windows, etc.

I want to prevent Windows associating new file extensions. That is, if I want to open a file `Read.me` (from a Linux environment) I want to be able to open it with Wordpad or Notepad but I do not want Windows to associate the extension `.me` with Wordpad or Notepad.

How can I

1. always have Notepad and/or Wordpad available on the right-click “open with” menu?
2. stop Windows from automatically associating the file extension with the selected program.

I need something simple and non-intrusive, with no side effects. And I do not want to use external programs such as Notepad++. I want to use Notepad and/or Wordpad, as I said. Keep it within the Windows 8 operating system.

Comment: Software like Notepad++ puts `"Edit with Notepad++"` by default on right click menu

Comment: I want to do this within the OS; I do not use Notepad++; I want Microsoft solving my anxiety every time they decide to add a new association.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a registry hack to add an *Open with Notepad* option in the right-click menu for all files, without affecting file associations. This is similar to what Notepad++ does when it is installed, except you don't need to install anything.

1. Press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> to open the Run dialog.
2. Type `regedit` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
3. Navigate to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell`
4. Right-click on **shell**
5. Choose to create a new key, calling it `Open with Notepad` or something similar
6. Create a new key below that one called `command`
7. Double-click on the **(Default)** value in the right-hand pane and enter the following:

   `notepad.exe %1`
8. The new option should appear in the context menus straight away without needing a restart

If you wanted to you could repeat the same steps but for Wordpad instead of Notepad.

This is based on [this article from How-To Geek](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/add-open-with-notepad-to-the-context-menu-for-all-files/) which was originally written for Windows Vista but seems to work for Windows 8.

Comment: This is definitely a step in the right direction. What I'd really like better it's just adding Notepad and Wordpad as always available  options for "Open Width". "Open Width" is controlled somehow by that evil MS extension engine. I'm looking for that info. I also want to stop/control the association mechanism.

Comment: For me, Notepad and Wordpad appear in the list of programs in the Open With dialog. If you manually pick an application by clicking **More options** then **Look for another app on this PC** then the application will be shown in the list whenever you click the **More options** link. However, the issue seems to be that after doing this once, Windows will no longer show the *Use this application for all .blah files* checkbox. Once a file has an association you can use the **Open with** menu option further down to manually pick a program. It will then keep track of which programs you have used.

Comment: it is not like that. Wordpad and Notepad appear after the MS engine already "worked" on that extension. i.e. if you have a file w/o extension you do not get the Wordpad/Notepad options. Besides that if you use i.e. Notepad on an new extension without checking the association check box that's the last time you see that checking box; next time you click on that extension the option for no association is now gone and you are screwed (the association is created)...

Comment: @James, Why are the other context menus like "Notepad++" and "7Zip" not listed under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell`?

Answer (score 1):

If you open the file from inside Notepad it won't be associated (*File* -> *Open* in the menu bar). [Also have a look at the video demonstration on youtube.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nG01T7MMX5A)

Comment: I open millions of configuration files, and other files I do not even know anything about its content. Do you consider practical opening Notepad then do an File/Open? there must be something better.

Comment: @Pat, I don't quite understand your comment. Why is it not practical? Just do a Win+R type in `notepad` and then type Ctrl-O.